# audio conference in my asterisk server,

Tags: asterisk

I tried to configure the audio conference in my asterisk server, but during the test, the audio conference could not be establishes. 
Here are the lines I added to the configuration files from my server:

**meetme.conf:**

```
conf => 999
```

**extension.conf:**

```
exten => 999, 1, Meetme (999)
```

Comment: You need to give us a bit more context to work with. What kind of error do you have, what else do you have in your config, what kind of log messages do you see ...

Answer (score 0):

You also need install asterisk-dahdi and dahdi-linux packages or recompile asterisk with dahdi support.

Conference not work without dahdi

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use dahdi (which builds kernel modules), you can use alternatives like
http://sourceforge.net/projects/appkonference/

It's easy to build/use, but most likely not packaged in any distro.

Answer (score -1):

Since Asterisk 10, Asterisk has included a fully-featured Conferencing application, `app_confbridge`, which, for almost all use-cases, replaces the older, now-deprecated `app_meetme`.

If the previous commenters were correct that your issue (it's hard to be sure without seeing the Asterisk CLI output) was due to missing kernel modules required for `MeetMe` and `DAHDI` usage, then `Confbridge`, if you're using Asterisk >= 10, would provide you with a nice remedy